# Unable to grab a field in Web Scraping Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab all the Company names(highlighted) from the below site. This is my first web scraping work so i'm trying hard to understand why am i not able to grab the company names though i've the right parameters in place,

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'} # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
request = requests.get("https://www.hispanicmeetings.org", verify=False, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.content)
soup.find_all("a href") # this is not getting me company names
soup.find_all('alt') #this either
```

I tried many little combinations with the help of the html tags i found the webpage but nothing seems to work.Any suggestion to grab all the company names to one place would mean alot to me.

Comment: call that [url](https://www.cloudtango.org/list/?page=1&country=&service=&partner=&locality=&postal_town=&administrative_area_level_1=&administrative_area_level_2=&administrative_area_level_3=&autocomplete=&head_office=&coordenades_lat=&coordenades_lng=&orderby=&order=) and loop over `page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correctly referencing the correct tags and/or attributes with BeautifulSoup. I'd suggest find a little tutorial on html to understand tags and attributes, then see how you select them with bs4. Then you can see how you pull out tags, and from those tags, pull out the text and/or attribute values. Try this code below:

```
import requests
import bs4

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'} # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
request = requests.get("https://www.cloudtango.org", verify=False, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all('td', {'class':'company'})

for each in data:
    print(each.find('img')['alt'])
```

**Output:**

```
Managed Solution
Redcentric
First Focus
K3 Technology
ICC Managed Services
AffinityMSP
BCA IT, Inc.
CloudCoCo Plc (formerly Adept4 PLC)
SCC
Datacom Systems
Compugen
Cancom
All Covered
Computacenter
q.beyond AG
Atos
Controlware GmbH Firmenzentrale
Trustmarque
Bytes
AHEAD
ACP IT Solutions GmbH
PROFI Engineering Systems AG
PQR
Orbit GmbH
SVA System Vertrieb Alexander GmbH
Ensono
Phoenix Software Ltd
Atea Norge AS
Axians
Kick ICT Group
Atea Sverige AB
Catapult Systems LLC
Valid
```

Comment: Thank you much!! but why "image" and "alt" inside two different tags in the code? They seem to be under one tag inside the html ( <image alt> )

Comment: if you get time, find a beginner html tutorial. the tag is `<img>`, and `alt` is an attribute in the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Got it! Gracias muchas

Comment: No worries! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The Company name is present as the `alt` attribute of the `img` tag inside the `<td>` tags with class name - company.

You are using `soup.find_all('alt')` - `alt` is not a tag.
Only HTML tags can be selected from soup objects and not attributes.

```
import requests
import bs4

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'} # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
request = requests.get("https://www.cloudtango.org", verify=False, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')

t = soup.findAll('td', class_='company')

for i in t:
    print(i.find('img')['alt'])
```

```
Output:

First Focus
Managed Solution
centrexIT
Carbon60
Redcentric
BlackPoint IT Services
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thank you Ram but why are you using ('img')['alt']) inside two different tags? Like in the html why is not one ?

Comment: ```<img>``` is a Tag and ```alt``` is an attribute of ```img``` tag. In my code I'm selecting the ```alt``` present inside ```img```. And you are selecting ```alt``` which is an attribute (Only HTML tags can be selected from soup objects and not attributes.)