# Webscraping specific fields in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

How can I extract the company and its description from here?

From my yesterday's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301420/unable-to-grab-a-field-in-web-scraping-python/68301479?noredirect=1#comment120791279_68301479) I figured out how names are extracted but when I applied the same logic to extract their description it backfired.

```py
request = requests.get("https://www.clstack.com", verify=False, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all('td', {'class':'company'})

for i in data:
    print(i.find['tr'])
```

output

```
company|description
```

The desc is inside 'td' tag but when I call it from code, I don't get any output.

Comment: there is no class associated with the desc tag which is adding more confusion to my understanding.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full traceback from the error.

Comment: there is not output that is the error.lol

Comment: @Byte Obviously there will be no output. `td` tag does not have any `tr` tag. `td` is inside `tr`

Comment: then how to access the description and company names at the same time? html is my first time so tutorials are not really helping and i'm very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice that the `<td class="company">` tags are followed by another `<td>` tag with the the description. So once you're iterating through the `<td class="company">` element, simply use the `.find_next('td')` to get that next tag with the description:

```
import requests
import bs4

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'} # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
request = requests.get("https://www.cloudtango.org", verify=False, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all('td', {'class':'company'})

for each in data:
    company =  each.find('img')['alt']   
    description = each.find_next('td').text
    print(f'{company}: {description}\n\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Redcentric: Redcentric is a leading UK IT managed services provider that offers a range of IT and Cloud services designed to support organisations in their journey from traditional infrastructure to the Cloud …


Modern Networks: Established in 1999, Modern Networks is a leading provider of IT support, network services, business broadband and telecoms to the UK’s commercial property sector. Additionally, we work with around …


BlackPoint IT Services: BlackPoint’s comprehensive range of Managed IT Services is designed to help you improve IT quality, efficiency and reliability -and save you up to 50% on IT cost. Providing IT solutions for more …


AffinityMSP: AffinityMSP was created with one goal in mind: to help Australian businesses achieve success through high-performance technology. Our consultants take the time to get to know your business and …


centrexIT: Founded in 2002, centrexIT is San Diego's leader in IT management. Our locally-based technology professionals provide outsourced IT service, support, security and leadership for small and medium-…


Carbon60: Carbon60 specializes in delivering secure managed cloud solutions for public and private sector organizations with business-critical workloads. Businesses are at different stages in their cloud …


...
```